# Google API Add row at position Google Spreadsheet PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to add a row in the second position of my sheet with php but it is not working, instead I am getting erros:
It is asking to

```
$worksheetSheets = $service->spreadsheets->get($sp)->sheets;
foreach($worksheetSheets as $sheet){ 
    $sheetID = $sheet->properties['sheetId'];     
    break;
}
$service = parent::GoogleServiceSheets();


$requestSingle = new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
    'updateDimensionProperties' => [
        'range'=> new \Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionRange([
            "startIndex"=>1,
            "endIndex"=>2,
            "dimension"=>"ROWS",
            "sheetId"=>$sheetID   
        ]),
        'properties'=> new Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionProperties([
            "hiddenByUser"=> True,                 
        ]),
        'fields' => 'ROW'
    ]
]);
$requests[] = $requestSingle;



$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($sp, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to add some row in a specific position right?
If that is the case:

```
$worksheetSheets = $service->spreadsheets->get($sp)->sheets;
foreach($worksheetSheets as $sheet){ 
    $sheetID = $sheet->properties['sheetId'];     
    break;
}
$service = parent::GoogleServiceSheets();

$requestSingle = new \Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
    'insertDimension' => array(
        'range' => array(
            'sheetId' => $sheetID,
            'dimension' => 'ROWS', 
            'startIndex' => 1,  
            'endIndex' => 2,
        ),
        'inheritFromBefore' => true 
    ) 
]);
$requests[] = $requestSingle;
$batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($sp, $batchUpdateRequest);
```